# javascript how to print star pattern on same line

Tags: javascript

I want to print diamond pattern using *. Please find the code below:

```
for (let i=0; i<num; i++) {
    let str="";
    for (let j=i; j<num; j++) {
        str+="*";
    }
    console.log(str);
}

for (let i=num; i>0; i--) {
    let spaces=num-i;
    let spacesStr="";
    for (let j=0; j<spaces; j++) {
        spacesStr+=" ";
    }
    let str=spacesStr;
    for (let j=i; j>0; j--) {
        str+="*";
    }
    console.log(str);
}
```

The output of the above code is as below:

```
****
***
**
*
****
 ***
  **
   *
```

I know that if I start printing both the patterns from line 1 I can achieve the desired output. But not sure how I can do that. Please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've quite figured out the answer already. You will need 3 for loops inside your main loop inorder to get that pattern.

```
let num = 5;
let string = "";

for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
  // printing star
  for (let j = 0; j < num - i; j++) {
    string += "*";
  }
  // printing spaces
  for (let k = 0; k < i * 2; k++) {
    string += " ";
  }

  // printing stars
  for (let l = num - i; l > 0; l--) {
    string += "*";
  }
  string += "\n";
}

console.log(string);
```

First, we print the left stars, then we print the spaces, and then again we print the right stars.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to build each line.

First, let's focus on the top half of the diamond.

- On the first line, there are `n` stars, `0` spaces, `n` stars.
- On the second line, there are `n-1` stars, `2` spaces, `n-1` stars.
- On the third line, there are `n-2` stars, `4` spaces, `n-2` stars.
- And the pattern follows till there are `0` stars.

Now, coming to the bottom half of the diamond, the pattern is same, just reversed. So, for the inner loops, you can just change `i` to `n-i` and `n-i` to `i`.

```js
const n = 5;
const star = "*";
const space = " ";

// Top half of the diagram
for (let i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
  let pattern = ''
  for (let j = 0; j < (n - i); j++) pattern += star;
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) pattern += `${space}${space}`;
  for (let j = 0; j < (n - i); j++) pattern += star;
  console.log(pattern);
}

// Bottom half of the diagram
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i ++) {
  let pattern = ''
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) pattern += star;
  for (let j = 0; j < (n - i); j++) pattern += `${space}${space}`;
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) pattern += star;
  console.log(pattern);
}
```